# sending form data in email

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a contact sales form.I want to get this form data in my email id, when the person filles the values then all values data show me in the form of table in the email. i have used following code that do not shows the values entered by user
 html:

```
 <tr>
        <td width="298">First Name <span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></td>
        <td width="37">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="297">Last Name <span style="color:#FF0000">* </span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="fname" class="saleform" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="lname" class="saleform" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Company <span style="color:#FF0000">* </span></td>
        <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Job Title <span style="color:#FF0000">* </span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="company" class="saleform" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="job" class="saleform" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Phone No <span style="color:#FF0000">* </span></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Email Id <span style="color:#FF0000">* </span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="phone" class="saleform" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="email" class="saleform" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Comment and Question<span style="color:#FF0000"> *</span></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><inp/td>
          <textarea name="messages" class="saleform" style="width:647px; height:100px;"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="submit"  class="button" value="Submit" align="left" style="margin-right:9px;" />
          <input name="button2" type="reset"  class="button" style="margin-right:9px;" value="Clear" align="left" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="297">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below :) and customise :)

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
  {
  //send email
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
  mail("someone@example.com", $subject,
  $message, "From:" . $email);
  echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
  }
else
//if "email" is not filled out, display the form
  {
  echo "<form method='post' action='mailform.php'>
  Email: <input name='email' type='text'><br>
  Subject: <input name='subject' type='text'><br>
  Message:<br>
  <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
  </textarea><br>
  <input type='submit'>
  </form>";
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```